# Extracted Feature to the csv file

Tags: extract, resnet

train_feature.shape (972, 4096) train_label.shape (972,)

i am using python codes, i want to write these featrues and labels to the csv file, i am using google colab i am using python codes and colab, pytroch. extracted feature and labels will use for other machine learning program.
I am trying to convert images tensor that and I want to save this into a file,  preferrably a csv file. I already have the image array in the dimension I want them but now the problem is saving to a file. Please how do I go about doing this.